# How to add a column which has three different values at varying lengths?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I have three lists "A","B","C" which contains 10 ,20 30 values respectively.I need to create a dataframe as shown below

```
Values                   Type
------                  ------ 
ListA_values              A
     .                    A
     .                    A
ListB_Values              B
     .                    B
     . 
ListC_Values              C
     .                    C
     .                    C
     .                    C
```

The columns here are Values and Type. Sorry Couldnt draw a better figure.
      .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Type': ['A']*100})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Type': ['B']*75})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Type': ['C']*80})

#Concatenate the DataFrames
df=df1.append(df2).append(df3).reset_index(drop=True)

df.loc[df['Type']=='A','Values']='ListA_values'
df.loc[df['Type']=='B','Values']='ListB_values'
df.loc[df['Type']=='C','Values']='ListC_values'

df=df[['Values','Type']]
```

A more efficient way will be -

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Type': ['A']*100})
df1.index = ['ListA_values'] * len(df1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Type': ['B']*75})
df2.index = ['ListB_values'] * len(df2)
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Type': ['C']*80})
df3.index = ['ListC_values'] * len(df3)

#Concatenate the DataFrames
df=df1.append(df2).append(df3)
df['Values'] = df.index
df=df.reset_index(drop=True)
df=df[['Values','Type']]

df
Out[31]: 
         Values Type
0  ListA_values    A
1  ListA_values    A
2  ListA_values    A
3  ListA_values    A
4  ListA_values    A
5  ListA_values    A
6  ListA_values    A
..            ...  ...
252  ListC_values    C
253  ListC_values    C
254  ListC_values    C
```

Comment: What if i have 100  'A' values  75 'B' Values and 80 'C' values?

Comment: I have made the changes. You can copy the code exactly.

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer if it helped you?

Comment: Lol sure! :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you have lists, I'd create a dictionary and then use `pd.concat` + the default `DataFrame` constructor to make your `DataFrame`

```
import pandas as pd

# Whatever your values are, whatever the size.
A = ['ListA_values']*40 
B = ['ListA_values']*80
C = ['ListA_values']*90

d = {'A': A, 'B': B, 'C': C}

pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(v, columns=['Values']).assign(Type=k) for k,v in d.items()], ignore_index=True)
```

#### Output:

```
           Values Type
0    ListA_values    A
1    ListA_values    A
2    ListA_values    A
3    ListA_values    A
4    ListA_values    A
5    ListA_values    A
..            ...  ...
206  ListA_values    C
207  ListA_values    C
208  ListA_values    C
209  ListA_values    C
```